# Rails 3: Scope returns an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I am using a scope to get an Item for a specific user:

In Item model

```
belongs_to :user    
scope :for_user, lambda { |user| where(:user_id => user) }
```

User model

```
has_many :items
```

**Problem**

When calling `Item.includes(:user).for_user(3)` an Array is returned instead of an ActiveRecord relation.
I'd expect it to behave like `Item.includes(:user).find_by_user_id(3)`, which returns a ActiveRecord relation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you do some more investigation you'll find ou that it does indeed return a relation object.

But it will when necessary convert it into an array.

Namely, if you're in a console and say `> Item.includes(:user).for_user(3)` it will try to inspect it, and consequently do the conversion.

But by all means the following will work

```
scope = Item.includes(:user).for_user(3)

# does a db count
scope.count

# does a db select limit 1
scope.first

# does a full db select
scope.all
```

Comment: ah.. when you say "ActiveRecord relation object" do you mean "an ActiveRecord" or an "ActiveRecord relation"? These are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Using `where(:user_id => user)` instead of dynamic method like find_by_user_id would always return an array. If you're only interested in the first record returned from your scope you can change your scope to be something like

```
scope :for_user, lambda { |user| where(:user_id => user).first }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It does the following: SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`name` = 'Berlin' LIMIT 1
 SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities`. And by that end up with an array of all.