# Rails3.2 undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Model called Status, its handling a table with two columns Stat and Colour.

Since these columns are also Model methods I would expect the following to work without an error

```
@a = Status.where(:stat => "Operational")
@a.colour = "Green"
```

However when I call @a.colour I receive an error stating that the method 'colour=' does not exist.

I am calling @a.colour from within seeds. This is just a model, it does not have a controller with it.

What am i doing wrong?

--Edit--

Model

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

schema

```
  create_table "statuses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "stat"
    t.string   "colour"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

Is this what you requested? I did not fully understand the request,

Kind Regards

Comment: Please post the definition of the model and the definition of the scheme creating the model in database (if that's the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `Status.where()` returns more than one record. So you are trying to call the `color=` method on an array which obviously does not exist!

So you need to iterate trough all found records, using

```
Status.where(:stat => "Operational").each do |a|
   a.colour = "Green"
end
```

For more information check the [Rails ActiveRcord Query Interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions), it tells you:

> If you’d like to add conditions to your find, you could just specify them in there, just like Client.where("orders_count = '2'"). This will find **all** clients where the orders_count field’s value is 2.

Comment: It only returns one record because there is only one "operational", and I have confirmed that it is only one record through the rails console

Comment: Are you sure? According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901499/rails-3-scope-returns-an-array the scope methodsalways return an array. (I cannot check it at the moment myself)

Comment: Positive, here is the console output 
irb(main):011:0> @a = Status.where(:stat => "Operating")
  ←[1m←[35mStatus Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE "s
tatuses"."stat" = 'Operating'
=> [#<Status id: 1, stat: "Operating", colour: nil, created_at: "2013-01-18 09:1
5:31", updated_at: "2013-01-18 09:15:31">]

Comment: The `[]` around the result indicate it is an array... (with in your case only one contained value, of which the values/records are shown within the `<>`)

Comment: You are right Veger, in that case how would i receive just one value?

Comment: Write a wrapper method, that grabs the first element from the returned array. Or just assume that you have (always) multiple returned records and use the example code snippet I provided at all locations.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will take the wrapper method path, the other style doesn't feel right for some reason

Comment: The wrapper will fail once you have more than one item returned from the `where`. The other style is the one you should be using, otherwise your code might break at some point.